# How use the San Francisco font to design the interface in Qt/QML programm for ios?

Tags: ios, qt, fonts, qml

Program for iOs is developed in Qt/qml/c++. I want use the San Francisco font, recommended by apple
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/
How can I set this font for qml components?

`Qt.fontFamilies()` (ios 12.1.2 / Qt 5.12.3) does not contain the font name "San Francisco".
If I'm not mistaken, qt on ios uses the font "Helvetica Neue" by default"

Comment: Did you try to load the font using [FontLoader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html)?

Comment: @folibis That is, the need to download the font and deliver it with the program is assumed?

Answer (score 0):

To use any font application wide (including in QML) you have to set it in your main.cpp as follows:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setFont(QFont("MyFontFamily"));
```

Of course the font has to be available. Execute this at startup to check if your font is already installed on the system:

```
for (const QString &family : QFontDatabase().families()) {
    qDebug()<<family;
}
```

In case it wasn't, you have to download it and add it to the resource file to be deployed with your application. You can add new fonts as follows:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);    

QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("://fonts/MyFontFamily-Regular.ttf");
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("://fonts/MyFontFamily-Italic.ttf");
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("://fonts/MyFontFamily-Bold.ttf");

app.setFont(QFont("MyFontFamily"));
```